# disable/enable auto increment in MSAccess via query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, auto-increment

During data transfer I want to:

**disable/enable Auto Increment columns in MSAccess**

So I can get the exact value which is inserted by my C# App via a query in MSAccess.

In MSSQL we could do it this way to enable:

```
sqlCmdDes.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT  dbo." + row["Table_Name"] + " ON";
```

and disable auto increment:

```
sqlCmdDes.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT  dbo." + row["Table_Name"] + " ON";
```

Comment: You cannot. You can insert into a subsidiary table or you can get a count of records inserted.

Comment: Even if you could, it would cause problems with simultaneous activity.

Comment: This is the solution to my question . Looking all the time for it.
Good Shot . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374375/keep-value-of-autonumber-column-when-importing-into-microsoft-access-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert specific value into identity (counter) column in Access without setting  IDENTITY_INSERT at all.
Simply use INSERT statement.

Comment: How can i specify my own value in identity column? they are autoNumbers. 
I can rest value to zero but that is not required.Can you show me with an example?

Comment: Example (id is counter): insert into Table_name(id) values(999); Simply try it. 999 should not be among existing values.

Comment: It did not worked. I copied data from Sql server to DataTable and then using OleDbCommandBuilder i inserted in MSAccess table , but MSAccess followed the new sequence and did not saved Auto Increment column values of insert command. e.g. I tried to save 2,3,4,8,9 but MSAccess saved 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: It works for me, if I insert values from another table into counter field also. Ex.

insert into tab(id)
select id
FROM Tbl;

Comment: you are right the small point i missed was that i will need to specify column names .